# PyWinAuto opening applications, but not returning any window dialogs

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywinauto

I am attempting to write a script to automate the setup of a new development machine. I have been using PyWinAuto to try to automate the installation of various programs which mostly use WinForm (or similar) GUI windows.

PyWinAuto opens the application properly, but does not return any windows. I have installed SWAPY and it shows me controls that I expect to see, but they do not work in the code. I tried using PyWinAuto 0.6.3 as well as 0.5.4 with Python 2.7.13 and 2.7.12 respectively (I am on a Windows 7 32-bit machine) and nothing has worked.

Here are examples of errors I am getting:

```
    import pywinauto
    from pywinauto.application import Application

    app = Application()
    app.Start("C:\setup.exe")
    appSetup = app.Setup
    appSetup.Wait('ready')
    ...
    ...
    Error: pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError: timed out
```

or

```
    app = Application()
    app.Start("C:\setup.exe")
    appSetup = app.Setup
    appSetup.ClickInput()
    ...
    ...
    Error: pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'Setup' in '[]'
```

Here is an example of one installation that I am getting errors on:
[Boost Install Window with SWAPY Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68Qds.png)

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: First you need more long name "app.SetupBoostWindow", after that just call method .Wait("ready", timeout=10) that will wait for window opening more than default 5 sec. See "Waiting for Long Operations" section in the docs. Sorry, typing from phone.

Comment: pywinauto 0.6.3 is more stable, so I'd recommend using the latest version. The Getting Started Guide describes the main concept so it will save you some time in the future.

Comment: Hi @VasilyRyabov I have tried both a more descriptive name and calling .Wait with "ready"; the .Wait function results in a runtime error saying the window is not responding. I will switch back to 0.6.3 now - was just confused since the latest release of SWAPY shows that it is using pywinauto 0.5.4. so I thought it could be an issue with that.

Comment: SWAPY is just not maintained currently. It doesn't support new MS UI Automation backend introduced in 0.6.0. But for legacy "win32" backend pywinauto 0.6.3 is mostly backward compatible with 0.5.4. Please update your question if the error output is changed in newer version.

Comment: Hi @VasilyRyabov thank you for your quick reply! After switching back to pywinauto 0.6.3 I was still getting the same errors. I tried using the win32 backend as well as starting AND connecting to the application window, and it worked! I think the key was both starting and connecting afterwards - I had similar problems to [this issue](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/209) raised. Thank you very much for your help! Cheers :-)

Comment: Aha, your app spawns one more process while starting. Glad you've figured it out. You can answer your own question and mark the answer as accepted to indicate it for others. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem occurs when the application you are targeting spawns a new process after starting. To fix this problem (with help from @VasilyRyabov - thank you!), I start the application as I did before (app.start("C:\setup.exe") and then *connect* the application (app.connect(title="Setup")) so you are connected to the process that is running the GUI window.

In some cases I have had to add a delay between these two functions if it does not spawn the second process fast enough.
[This issue](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/209) posted on GitHub is very similar to this scenario.

Comment: Worked like magic!